# how to search files modified between a specific time in a date

Tags: terminal, finder, filesystem, search, search-engine

In mac os, how can I search the files modified or used within a specified timespan on a date?

For example i want to get the files used between 10am to 4pm on 10/30/2018. Can this be done either via finder or terminal?

Comment: I have tried using search options available in the finder with used dates etc. and so far i can only get the files with the date and unable to filter to the time

Answer (score 1):

A terminal based approach would use mdfind (the CLI Spotlight too).

Using **mdls** on a file you can see all the attributes available to you, something like kMDItemContentModificationDate looks like what you want.

So, the mdfind command would be something like

```
mdfind 'kMDItemContentModificationDate < $time.iso(2018-10-30T16:00:00) && kMDItemContentModificationDate > $time.iso(2018-10-30T10:00:00)'
```

You can chain together any combination of the attributes returned from mdls.

Apple Dev docs here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you tell me how can i do the same search with usedDates. Because usedDates has more than one value on it

Comment: Years later... this is partially useful. Can someone clarify where to find the components of this command? Can we use `==` or `~` instead of `<` and `>` - where is this documented? Where do you find the construction for date with an expression `$time.iso(xxxx)`?

Comment: Here’s the man page: https://ss64.com/osx/mdfind.html it details the available comparison operators, which includes equality, but not partial sub string matching. More details here, which includes wildcards: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/SpotlightQuery/Concepts/QueryFormat.html